# How do I change the color of a variable sent to a function to create a PDF?

Tags: php, colors

I am working on creating a PDF from a page on a website.  There are predefined functions already that format text, etc., but I don't see how to change the color of specific words. The code is:

`$pdfobj->$job['reference'];`

The whole lot then gets sent to an output function. Is there a way to do this without using CSS or an echo statement? TIA.

ADDED: it is using Cpdf, but I can only find command line examples to change the color.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which PDF library are you using?

Comment: Are you sure about `$pdfobj->$job['reference'];`? I think, this sould be `$pdfobj->{$job['reference']}();`

Comment: That's what the other code is, @Philipp. I am just "copying" what the other people did and going from there.

Comment: pdflib, I believe.  I am pretty new at this.  Sorry, Cpdf.